# Laravel Routing URL issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am not so sure what is wrong with the following issue (I am using PHP with laravel). I have a main template with header and footer. I have a view (Register) for creating some request (view, controller and model). Everything is fine so far. Now, I am trying to add an edit view  and created a new view (RegisterEdit - same as previous view) but just with values populated for the given id. In this new view, all the links (header and footer) on the page are wrongly pointed.

In the old view, the link to home page is like this:

```
  mywebsite.com/home
```

But in the edit view, this is being changed to

```
mywebsite.com/RegisterEdit/home
```

Following are my routes.

```
Route::get('Register', 'CreateRequestController@Page_Load');
Route::post('Register', 'CreateRequestController@CreateRequest');
Route::get('RegisterEdit/{id}', 'CreateRequestController@Page_Load');
Route::post('RegisterEdit', 'CreateRequestController@CreateRequest');
```

Any idea, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code for your header and footer? It seems like its an issue with relative vs. absolute linking rather than your routes file.

Comment: I was suspecting the same but my concern was how is it working with the rest of the views. I have noticed this issue with all the include files. For ex. {{HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.js')}}, doesn't get loaded either (they work fine in other views). This is my URL "<a href="Profile">Profile</a>" (modifying this to /Profile) works though. But I am interested in why it is working in other views.

Comment: If you use the code `<a href="{{ url('home') }}">Home</a>` in your views then you shouldn't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

To create urls in your code you should use `URL::to`, for example:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('home')">Home page</a>
```

or you should add in your `<head>` section of your header:

```
<base href="http://mywebsite.com/">
```

(trailing slash is required here after domain name).

Comment: This change works as well. But I was wondering why its working in other places. Similarly, all my include files are having the same issue (js files). (/js/bootstrap.min.js) is changed to (RegisterEdit/js/bootstrap.min.js).

Comment: @Chandra This is because if you don't use absolute paths (with http at the beginning) all your urls are relative to current path, so if you are in `mywebsite.com/RegisterEdit` directory `home` will be appended to this path, to prevent it, you need to either use base href (all urls will be relative to base href) or use everywhere absolute paths

Comment: Thanks Marcin. That's a fair point and I'm aware of it. My issue is when I am in mywebsite.com/Register, it points to mywebsite.com/home but when I am in mywebsite.com/RegisterEdit, it is pointing to mywebsite.com/RegisterEdit/home. I will just look over it once again.